# Sentence with more than one conjugated verb

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I read that when you have two verbs in a sentence the second one should be in the infinitive form.

So I saw the line below (may well be incorrect in which case my question is moot).

So we have *creer* conjugated in the first person singular, *"creo"* but then we also have *estar* in the conjugated form *"estoy"*, how is that? *Tratando* is in the gerund form and *forzar* in the infinitive form which seems in keeping with the rules I learnt.

> Creo que estoy tratando de forzarlo -> I think I am trying to force it.

Comment: Us natives sometimes don't know those "rules" since for us something sounds natural without thinking on rules but I guess the rule you are talking about is not true.  It is the same in your English example where: Infinitive _to force=forzar_. Gerund _trying=tratando_, Singular/present _I think=creo_.

Comment: I think the rule is not true. A simpler example: Creo que estoy enfermo (I think I'm sick). That's a valid sentence and it has no infinitive verb.

Comment: @MauricioMartinez  "estoy enfermo" are not two conjugated verbs,  "enfermo" is an adjective

Comment: @Mike my example is "[creo] que [estoy] enfermo". Both, "creer" and "estar", are conjugated.

Comment: I see so maybe its not hard rule more a general guide then

Comment: @MauricioMartinez  the OP is asking when a verb is being conjugated after another verb 
"creo" is one conjugation with the pronoun "yo"
"estoy" is another conjugation with the pronoun yo" 
Yo creo que yo estoy

Comment: @Mike Yes, an example similar to sentence in the question: "_Creo que estoy_ tratando de forzarlo -> I think I am trying to force it."

Comment: if you want to conjugate two verbs together in that pattern you have to say "Creo estar" and not "Creo que estoy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If there are two verbs in a sentence the second one should be in the infinitive form" is certainly not a rule that I would teach. Make that "in some verb phrases a verb that is usually conjugated is followed by another verb that is in the infinitive form", and you'll have something that does work in some specific contexts, with some specific verbs.

For example, it works in certain propositions where the main verb is *poder*, *deber*, *querer*, *tratar*, *creer*, and others, some of which an English speaker would analyze as modal verbs (*can, should, must*) or as verbs that often take a subordinate verb (*want (to)*, *try (to)*).

- *No puedo creer lo que escucho.* = "I can't believe what I'm hearing."
- *Creo entenderte.* = "I think I understand you."
- *Deberíamos dejarlo solo.* = "We should leave him alone."
- *¿Quieres entrar?* = "Do you want to come in?"
- *Trataré de hablar con ella.* = "I will try to talk to her."

Now your example says:

> *Creo que estoy tratando de forzarlo.*

This is actually fairly complicated because there are three verbs and each one is subordinated to the previous one.

1. *Creer* is followed by *que*, indicating that what follows is a subordinate clause (as in English when preceded by an optional *that*).
2. The subordinate clause, *estoy tratando de forzarlo*, has a main verb *tratar* in the "present continuous" pseudo-tense. *Tratar* is commonly followed by another verb in the infinitive, subordinated using the preposition *de*, just as in English you would use *to* in *try to…*.
3. Finally there's the verb *forzar* with a direct object pronoun attached to it.

In each step you must know how the verb works with other verbs. *Creer* is often followed by full subordinate phrases, and *tratar de* is followed by infinitives, but the reverse can also be true:

- *Creo **estar tratando** de forzarlo.*
- *Creo que estoy tratando de **que se afloje**.* <sub>(*aflojar* = "to loosen")</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your rule says:

> When you have two verbs in a sentence the second one should be in the infinitive form

I think you were given this rule so that you wouldn't be tempted to try something like this:

> <strike>Creo estoy tratando de forzarlo.</strike>

"Creo estoy" (two conjugated verbs in a row) does not work.

But a rule of thumb like this shouldn't be applied on autopilot.  For example,

> Los sábados limpio la casa y voy al supermercado.

"Limpio **y** voy" -- that's fine, because they form a *list* of two.

And in your case, "Creo que estoy" works because each verb is in its own clause.

Reference explaining clauses in English (this concept holds in Spanish as well): http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/clause.htm

One could refine the rule, I suppose, and make it "When you have two verbs in a **clause**, the second one should be in the infinitive form," but I'm not sure I would bother.  As you continue to build more complex sentences I doubt you'll need that rule any more.