# when and when not to use the infinitive of a verb

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I'm not sure if this question should be added to my [my previous question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/sentence-with-more-than-one-conjugated-verb/23524#23524) from yesterday or not so fogrive / tell me if that is the case.

In that question I asked if it was always the case that when you have two verbs in a sentence the second one should be in the infinitive form. From which I learned that it was not the case.

One of the answers gave me this useful [webpage on clauses](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/clause.htm). So I was reading the example, the line below.

> Tara ate a cheese roll after she watched the news

1.Tara ate a cheese roll is an independent clause. It works as a standalone sentence.

2. The clause after she watched the news is a dependent clause. It does not work as a standalone sentence.

According to goolge translate (I am aware this is not always accurate) in Spanish the translation is the line below.

> Tara comió un rollo de queso después de ver las noticias

Should the "ver" be vio or visto?

Comment: In English you can say *after she watched* or *after watching*. In Spanish it's *después de que vio* or *después de ver*. It's basically the same (in this case), though English uses the *-ing* form in some contexts where Spanish uses the infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously the google translation is ok however as you suspected there are cases when you can use **vio** or **visto** but the meanings are different and you have to add some things for the sentence to make sense.

I'll give you the following examples

> Tara comió un rollo de queso **y** después **vio** las noticias.
>   Tara comió un rollo de queso **,**  después **vio** las noticias.

These two sentences translate to:

> Tara ate a cheese roll and after (that) she watched the news
>   Tara ate a cheese roll and afterwards   she watched the news

So she ate and at a later time watched the news.

> Tara comió un rollo de queso **y vio** las noticias.

Now this means.

> Tara ate a cheese roll and watched the news.

In this example both actions are in the past but both happened probably at the same time.

> Tara comió un rollo de queso,  después **de haber visto** las noticias.

And this translates to:

> Tara ate a cheese roll after having watched the news

Here she first watched the news and then ate.

I know this doesn't really answer when to use infinitive but it gives you and idea of when to use the other two conjugations and it's too long to be a comment :-)

Comment: thanks that is helpful actually, understand there isn't always a clear and cut rule. Tricky old things languages!

Comment: Actually *después de ver las noticias* would work fine as well, wouldn't it? In any case it would use an infinitive.

Comment: Thanks @pablodf76 I did not include that because it was what google gave him.

Comment: While a useful answer, i dont see why this should be accepted. It doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @BrianH. I agree and said exactly that but if the OP feels it is the answer he is looking for he is free to accept it. If you or somebody else have a better answer the OP can change his mind and accept that other answer. In the mean time it is what it is.